# Discord bot. OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python, discord, hosting

I'm making my Discord bot in Python and I use `repl.it` as a coding environment. Also, I've used `UptimeRobot` for hosting. But I experience `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use` error when I try to run the bot in repl.it. Even though it launches fine (except for `Errno 98`), I see, that my bot starts to reply twice. This is a little embarrassing because when I make changes in the code, it does not apply in Discord (either does apply, but it sends them twice: An old and new version of the command)

Does anybody know how to fix this error?

Thank you

Comment: It means the port is already used.

Comment: Hi! I've changed its port (to some other random numbers) but my bot still replies twice. I don't know, maybe I should stop UptimeRobot while I'm running the code in replit or something?

Comment: What's more fun: After some time passes, my changes apply to UptimeRobot hosted code (automatically). So I need to wait, presumably, 20 minutes, so my changes go into the hosted script. Do you know why?